# I cant access object that where on another layer in 2.79 in 2.8

Tags: layers, versions, visibility

I wanted to start working on my Blender file in the 2.8 version and when I started working in my existing 2.79 file in the 2.8 version i couldn't access the object that where on another layer in blender 2.79.

The objects do appear in the outliner but in a darker gray and I can't see them.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think they are hidden (can you provide a screenshot?), in that case you should be able to unhide them by unhiding all (alt+h) or by unhiding them from the outliner (with the eye icon).